# Expression springMacroRequestContext is undefined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, freemarker, htmlunit

I am trying to do freemarker unit test using htmlunit, junit and freemarker template.  But When i used <@spring.message "data"> it gave me this exception.

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression springMacroRequestContext is undefined on line 89, column 134 in spring.ftl.
at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)
at freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:78)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:86)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
```

Any idea about this exception, how i can fix this? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: at least for me it happens only when generating html inside java using `freemarker.template.Template.process` method. Seems that springMacroRequestContext is added to late to a model. 'Normal' usage of freemarker - by returning string with template name from controller - works without this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the proper way to handle this is, as I just spent about an hour trying to figure this out myself. But what worked for me is adding the "springMacroRequestContext" manually to the data model using the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(request, null, null, null));
```

Note that this still has to happen inside of a valid request. So this probably wont work in a cron job or scheduled task, as there's no current request.

Comment: You can mock the request if you have access to the `WebApplicationContext`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your Freemarker View Resolver in your Spring controllerContext.xml.  Specifically, add:

```
<property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
```

so it looks like:

```
<bean id="freemarkerViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you are trying to use `FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(Template t,Model m)` to get just the String output from a FreeMarker template. Spring recently deprecated Velocity and suggested to its users to use FreeMarker for writing emails, so I guess this is what a lot of people are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Brad Parks's answer on manually adding the `springMacroRequestContext`:

It is sufficient to have a reference to the `WebApplicationContext` (which can be easily accessed with `@Autowired` if your object is a bean in the WebApplicationContext) because you can mock the request:

```
// Declare WebApplicationContext as an instance variable
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext ctx;

// Then in the method...:
    // (The mock object is from the org.springframework.mock.web package)
    MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    // secret sauce:
    req.setAttribute(RequestContext.WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, ctx);
    // Create a MacroRequestContext for Freemarker to use
    model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(req));
```